# How to make sure a method is called after a change and not called anymore after another change in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have some test code using Mockito:

```
public class ProcessFunctionClass {

    public void processElement(Tuple2<String, String> tuple,
        Context context, Collector<Tuple2<String, String>> collector) {

        // if the state is empty, start a timer
        if (listState.get().iterator().hasNext() == false)
            context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(1000);

        listState.add("someStringToBeStored");

        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to call the `processElement()` first, then verify that the timer (`context.timerService()`) was started, then call `processElement()` again, and then verify that the timer was NOT started again. I don't want to use `verify()` saying the method has been called once overall; I want to test for exactly what I described. How can I do that in Mockito?

Here is my attempt:

```
    TimerService timerService = mock(TimerService.class);
    processFunctionClass.processElement(tuple1, context, collector);
    verify(timerService, times(1)).registerProcessingTimeTimer(anyLong()); // this passes as expected
    processFunctionClass.processElement(tuple2, context, collector);
    verify(timerService, times(0)).registerProcessingTimeTimer(anyLong()); // this fails as the method was called once before
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to do the change, verify the method has been called, do the second change, and verify the method has been called once in total. Looks like this is the most accurate way of describing it that is available.